# Sharepoint Rest API File Upload by Postman

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I was trying to upload xlsx file by Postman to my sharepoint but getting access denied issue. Not able to figure out what is wrong here.

Tried to provide FullControl permission via appinv.aspx mentioned below but issue still exists.
Please help here.

[image]

Comment: Added this permission xml:                                                                   AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"
  AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" 
AppPermissionRequests

Comment: Used below url to generate client id and secret : https://aaasapgmail.sharepoint.com/sites/FileSafe_D/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx